# While I perform GTMetrix test of my site it shows the following. How can I fix this?

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider, gtmetrix

Do anyone have an idea to solve this to increase page load time, please. My GTMetrix result shows the following:

The following resources have identical contents but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 108.0KiB.

http://eternalhimalaya.com/illionso_plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js
http://eternalhimalaya.com/illionso_plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?rev=5.4.8.3

The following resources have identical contents but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 63.4KiB.

http://eternalhimalaya.com/illionso_plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js
http://eternalhimalaya.com/illionso_plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?rev=5.4.8.3

When I disable the revolution slider plugin, it's all fine. But I'm a novice WordPress user and need that plugin as well. Is it a good idea to replace one jquery file by another by navigating to the above location?

Comment: Could you let us know which theme you are using? I saw this post about a problem with X theme: https://theme.co/apex/forum/t/serve-resources-from-a-consistent-url-revolution-slider/6997

Comment: I'm using Entrada Travel theme.

Comment: My guess is that your theme includes the Revolution Slider plugin, but you also have it installed separately? If that's the case you don't need the separate plugin. If that's not the issue, then you should probably contact the theme developer, hopefully they can help you.